# video decoding with out external space required for mediaelement in windows apps

Tags: c#

I want write a code for decoding video file of any format....currently I’m working visual studio community...my question is..we have a video with a container .mp4 or some of other containers... now i want to write a code to separate main video and audio from the container then I want to put them into some other container which my app supports...to do this operation in media element in windows application we have transcoding option but this process takes the space in hard disk...we have take a video file covert and save the converted file....i don't want to do that because the same won't work on mobile apps....so I want write a code which performs the

> 1. Remove video and audio from container
> 2. Take the media player current play time information feed with a container with required amount of file

So this won’t take any extra space.... the container I want to know is mp4, flv, mkv.

please help me with this... there some software which convert the video's any format to required format...my idea is same but i want to do in time parallel to media playing....